What is the grammatical role of "ensuring their sustained utilization over an extended period" in its sentence?

By their very nature, the concepts of maintenance and repair are predominantly examined from a process-oriented perspective. The focus in related scholarly discourse often revolves around the lifespan or lifecycle of objects and technologies. In this context, maintenance and repair are considered practices that have the potential to prolong the existence of objects, ensuring their sustained utilization over an extended period. Krebs and Weber critically engage with anthropomorphic metaphors that imply a biography of things, appropriately highlighting that conventional understanding of the lifecycle of a technology, from its acquisition to its disposal from the household, provides an incomplete definition. In reality, objects do not conform to a linear lifecycle model; instead, they undergo breakdowns, await repairs, are stored away, or find themselves relegated to the basement, only to be rediscovered and repurposed later. Additionally, objects may enter recycling or second-hand cycles, leading to a dynamic afterlife marked by diverse applications. As such, the life of an object exhibits a far more complicated and adaptive path than a simplistic linear progression.

Source: a reading passage from an English examination

Is the grammatical construction of the bold part "to, by ensuring their sustained utilization over an extended period, prolong the existence of objects" or is it "to prolong the existence of objects, because maintenance and repair ensure their sustained utilization over an extended period"?

The meaning of the passage you cite can be clarified by inserting a thereby or a thus immediately before the ensuring. Or by replacing the ensuring with a which will ensure.

@PaulTanenbaum What does "ensuring their sustained utilization over an extended period" modify?

It modifies practices. And the antecedent of the pronoun their is objects.

@PaulTanenbaum Could that part be rewritted as "practices that, ensuring their sustained utilization over an extended period, have the potential to prolong the existence of objects"?

No. But it could be rewritten as practices that ensure objects’ sustained utilization … by prolonging their existence.

The sentence doesn't make clear sense:

In this context, maintenance and repair are considered practices that have the potential to prolong the existence of objects, ensuring their sustained utilization over an extended period.

That which has "the potential to prolong ... existence" does not "ensure" anything.
But leaving that aside, the participial phrase introduced by ensuring has as its understood subject "practices that have the potential to prolong the existence of objects".
That participial phrase expresses a result.  One could put the word "thereby" in front of it.

Is your point that, even though that which has "the potential to prolong ... existence" does not really "ensure" anything, it does ensure their sustained utilization over an extended period according to the text in question?

My point is that if we read the sentence in a  "forgiving" manner, we can accept that the author probably means to say that prolonging the existence of objects ensures their sustained utilization.  In simple  terms, "Repairing broken things extends their useful life."

I get it. I wonder if, strictly speaking, the "ensuring" part is correct English.

ensuring is correct English.

It would seem to me that it is not naural to use "ensuring" in that context and that it is better to use "and to ensure". Am I right?

Ah, by "correct English" you dd not mean "grammatical" but something like "appropriate choice of words to express the idea".  Yes, your suggestion is an improvement:  "... maintenance and repair are considered practices that have the potential to prolong the existence of objects and ensure their sustained utilization over an extended period".  With that change, they are  "practices ... that have the potential ... to ensure their sustained utilization over an extended period". If I were the editor, I would  strike "prolong the existence of objects".

I understand. I'd like to ask some questions about some details of the passage. 1. In the "Additionally, objects may enter recycling or second-hand cycles, leading to a dynamic afterlife marked by diverse applications" part, is "recycling or second-hand cycles" short for "recycling cycles or second-hand cycles"? 2. Does "leading have as its understood subject "objects"? 3. Could one put the word "thereby" in front of "leading"?

There are two kinds of cycles, not necessarily mutually exclusive:  recycling, and second-hand.  (Recycling reuses the object primarily for materials, although that process could include removal of salvageable parts.  Second-hand cycles reuse the object primarily as a "used" working replacement, although that cycle could involve "cannibalization" of the object for working parts.)  The clause introduced by leading to expresses a result, and so "thereby" could be used to introduce the clause, or the clause could be introduced with "which leads to ..."

The understood subject of the verb "leading" is the fact itself, that "objects may enter recycling or second-hand cycles". (The fact) that objects enter such cycles leads to...  The modal may complicates this somewhat.  Same problem as before with "potential".   It is the fact that objects do enter such cycles that leads to a diverse afterlife for them, not that objects may enter such cycles.  So perhaps it would be better to use a second modal:  '... may enter ... cycles ... which can lead to a diverse afterlife for them'
